# Mismatch between tag description and tagged question - which one to choose?

Tags: discussion, tags

In an effort to improve tags on SO (and yes, get a nice silver badge), every now and then I try to edit and improve some tags.

In case of some tags that are more vague (i.e. are not obviously about some particular language, system, etc), I usually start by looking at the questions that are tagged with the tag in question.

From time to time I find a big mismatch between the existing tag description and the question. A good example is [quote](/questions/tagged/quote) tag. The existing description is about lisp but there are hardly any questions about lisp (at least recently).

Now, what should be done in those cases:

1. Should I edit the description to match the existing questions?
2. Should the questions be re-tagged (not really feasible)?
3. The tags that have this problem are usually not the best tags around? Should they be removed maybe?

Comment: Actually, `quote` isn't a bad choice for burnination IMO.

Comment: I don't think this has a "general" answer.  How to handle is going to vary based on the specific tags in question.  In this case, [tag:quote] should probably be renamed [tag:lisp-quote] to avoid the confusion that seems to have arrised from the incorrect usage, and then the tag needs removed from all non-lisp questions.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I disagree.  If used as intended (based on the wiki), the tag is perfectly valid, but it is not being used properly.

Comment: So what should we do?  Nuke everything without a corresponding `lisp` (and its dialects) tag on it?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy see my earlier comment, but basically everything needs retagged to remove the tag from anything that is not applicable to the `LISP quote` operator.  Doesn't mean that everything with [tag:lisp] needs it and doesn't mean it needs removed from anything without [tag:lisp].  You have to evaluate the questions 1-by-1 to ensure it is applicable.  And if in doing so, you discover a valid usage, then a new tag needs create.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I realize my earlier comment that I referenced you too was vague on the details, but my 2nd quote above should cover it.

Comment: Related question - [Quote tags cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203973).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, this is not a question that can be answered in generalities as there are far to many variables to address your questions without answering with questions.

When you encounter a tag that is used incorrectly per the tag wiki (and this is in any volume whether 1 question, 200, 2000, or 2 million), then you needed to ask yourself:

- Is the usage of this tag in the new question(s) worthy of a tag (any tag)?  If so, maybe you need to create a new tag for the new usage.  If not, then just remove it from all of the incorrectly tagged questions.
- Does the "incorrect" usage of the tag match an existing tag?  If so, then you just need to retag with the existing tag.
- Are the concepts/technologies referenced in the tag wiki (or original use of the tag) worthy of being a tag?  If not, then maybe the old tag needs removed or edited.
- Does the usage reference the same exact concept/technology, differing only in the base language or platform?  Then maybe the tag wiki needs expanded to cover multiple languages/platforms/versions.
- Are the concepts/technologies in "mistagged" question a more common usage of the name than the concepts/technologies described in current tag wiki?

  - If so, maybe the old usage of the tag needs a different tag (either another existing tag or a brand new one you create) and the old questions need retagged with this tag.
  - If not, then maybe both the old and new usages need their own less confusing tags

Be warned that cleaning up a tag, especially one that has been misused for a number of years is not for the faint of heart.  It can take a lot of work with retagging and writing new tag wikis.  So a couple of guidelines to keep in mind:

1. Don't start something you aren't prepared to see through the end (don't start and give up halfway through).  See #4 if you need help.
2. Don't edit/retag too many questions in one sitting.  Regardless of the activity level of the site, many users will get annoyed when they see the front page full of your edits.  Only do them a few at a time and try to space out your sessions.  How long depends on the site.  A low traffic site, you might only want to do 4 or 5 a day but on Stack Overflow you can probably get away with a series of questions every 30-60 minutes.
3. Don't do this unless you are 100% certain you are making the right choices.  Ask on meta if you have any doubts.
4. For large undertakings, use the site's meta (or chat) to recruit help, but still keep guideline #2 in mind.

---

Now for your specific example, [quote](/questions/tagged/quote), the tag wiki suggests that there is a quote operator in LISP that has special functionality, as such, the original usage of the tag seems to be appropriate.  But because "quote" is a common character that programmers often have to deal with, the existing tag could be very confusing.  A quick glance through the questions currently tagged [quote](/questions/tagged/quote) don't seem to point to any thing tag worthy, so I don't think any new tags are needed, but there seem to be a number of SQL questions, and I'm not well versed in SQL, so there could be something worthy of a tag there.

So I'd suggest the following:

- Rename [quote](/questions/tagged/quote) to [lisp-quote](/questions/tagged/lisp-quote) to eliminate the confusion
- Remove [quote](/questions/tagged/quote) on any questions that are not about the Lisp quote operator.
- If there is a new tag needed for any of the questions, make sure you create the tag and apply it to the necessary questions.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, especially the first part. I realise it's sometimes a huge task. Also, many times I just lack knowledge to make meaningful decisions. This is the case with [tag:quote]. I don't know much about lisp and thus I don't want to be the judge on what's right and wrong.

Comment: If you're not sure, ask on MSO, as you did.  You'll get advice.  Burninate is often an appropriate tag.